# How to use issues of Gitlab from terminal?

Tags: git, gitlab

I know you can use Github issues on the command line by installing ghi.

- [ghi](https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi)

However, is there any way to use similar tools for listing/adding/removing/editing issues of repositories on **Gitlab** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a similar wrapper (in python, not ruby) with [`Itxaka/pyapi-gitlab`](https://github.com/Itxaka/pyapi-gitlab)

```
git = gitlab.Gitlab(host=host)
git.login(user=user, password=password)
git.getall(git.getprojects)

git.getissues(page=1, per_page=40)
```

In ruby, that would be [`NARKOZ/gitlab`](https://github.com/NARKOZ/gitlab):

```
# set an API endpoint
Gitlab.endpoint = 'http://example.net/api/v3'
# => "http://example.net/api/v3"

# set a user private token
Gitlab.private_token = 'qEsq1pt6HJPaNciie3MG'
# => "qEsq1pt6HJPaNciie3MG"

# configure a proxy server
Gitlab.http_proxy('proxyhost', 8888)
# proxy server w/ basic auth
Gitlab.http_proxy('proxyhost', 8888, 'proxyuser', 'strongpasswordhere')

# list projects
Gitlab.projects(per_page: 5)
```

It can [fetch issues](https://github.com/NARKOZ/gitlab/blob/ac595af15a07601b3b657d4b4c1c479651aaa7d7/spec/gitlab/client/issues_spec.rb#L24).

Comment: Wow, thanks for your quirck response, @VonC! I have just installed pyapi-gitlab and seems working fine :)

Comment: @VonC: Where (location on filesystem and file) do we store the above endpoint and other details after installing NARKOZ/gitlab? CLI works when i exported GITLAB_API_ENDPOINT & GITLAB_API_PRIVATE_TOKEN but i have no clue where to save the config file.

Comment: @Technext there is no config file for that gem module, as mentioned in https://github.com/NARKOZ/gitlab/issues/159. There is a PR open though: https://github.com/vshn/puppet-gitlab/pull/44

Comment: Thanks for the links @VonC! :)

Answer (score 10):

GLab seems to be a great option.

> GLab is an open source Gitlab Cli tool written in Go (golang) to help work seamlessly with Gitlab from the command line. Work with issues, merge requests, watch running pipelines directly from your CLI among other features.

https://github.com/profclems/glab

Comment: Tool is now officially under GitLab, named [gitlab-cli](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like someone has written a CLI tool for gitlab's API:

https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html

```
pip3 install --user python-gitlab
$EDITOR ~/.python-gitlab.cfg
```

Sample config for gitlab's main site, but you can add your own local instances too:

```
[global]
default = gitlab
ssl_verify = true
timeout = 5

[gitlab]
url = https://gitlab.com
private_token = <insert API token here>
api_version = 4
```

Make sure your path inlcudes `/home/<username>/.local/bin/`

Then from within your gitlab repo:

```
gitlab issue list
```

I'm not sure if it's as complete as `ghi`, but it looks like it supports a good amount of the API.

Comment: Please note that `gitlab issue list` lists only the issues the user has created and by default lists only returns 20 items at a time because the output is paginated (Use --all to show the whole list). The output is the equivalent of "Issues I've created" because the scope of API defaults to `created_by_me`. See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/issues.html
(This currently can not be changed with the CLI tool).

Comment: JFTR: To list the issues of a project I use the following commands. The first command shows me the project_id and the second lists the issues of the project:

`gitlab project list` and `gitlab project-issue list --project-id PROJECT_ID --state opened [--page X | --all]`

Also see: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/issues.html#list-project-issues

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

At first I thought ghi would be also available on Gitlab, but after that I found out below issues of ghi, in which the owner of ghi says currently it does not support Gitlab.

Just in case you spend time searching for the compatibility between ghi and Gitlab usage.

> I'm not opposed to the feature (if introduced simply), but G.H.I. is definitely built around GitHub Issues. I'm also not a user of GitLab, so the enhancement would have to come from someone else.

https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi/issues/135

Comment: Have you tried `glab` https://github.com/profclems/glab

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not address your whole question, just a small part.

To create an issue programmatically you can use the [New issue via URL](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/create_issues.html#using-a-url-with-prefilled-values) feature.

It allows you to create an issue with a title and description (using a template if needed) via an URL with parameters.

The URL looks like this:

```
https://gitlab.instance.url/group_name/project_name/issues/new?issue[title]=Your%20issue%20title&issue[description]=Issue%20description
```

I've wrapped that in an AHK shortcut bound to <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. I've inlcuded the `URLEncode` function for completeness.

```
;; Create issue on Gitlab tasks list with selected text as issue title
^!t::
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
Sleep, 300
Send ^c
title := URLEncode(clipboard)
mainURL := "https://gitlab.instance.com/gitlab/group_name/project/issues/new?issue[title]="
fullURL := mainURL title
Run, %fullURL%
Clipboard := ClipSaved
return

UrlEncode( String )
{
    OldFormat := A_FormatInteger
    SetFormat, Integer, H

    Loop, Parse, String
    {
        if A_LoopField is alnum
        {
            Out .= A_LoopField
            continue
        }
        Hex := SubStr( Asc( A_LoopField ), 3 )
        Out .= "%" . ( StrLen( Hex ) = 1 ? "0" . Hex : Hex )
    }

    SetFormat, Integer, %OldFormat%

    return Out
}
```

Comment: the url for the gitlab wiki is now [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/create_issues.html#using-a-url-with-prefilled-values)